# Enable to deploy to different env from diffrent branch - rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have rails app with two branches `master`, `staging`

I have deployed with master to elasticbeanstalk successfully, and created another environment for staging and want to deploy staging branch when I do eb deploy it always takin master code to staging envb as well (I have downloaded zip from s3 which was shipped to staging env)

eb version - EB CLI 3.14.3 (Python 2.7.1)

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: Backend-Production
  staging:
    environment: Backend--Staging
global:
  application_name: DGL-Backend
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Puma with Ruby 2.5
    running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.2
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

I have no idea what's going on spent too many hours on it please suggest somehting to solve this??

`eb branch` these command do not work as its new version of eb cli

I am deploying code from my local git

Comment: Which branch are you in when you're deploying to staging ?

Comment: I am in    staging branch

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28988668/4160532). See if you have missed any of those steps.

Comment: You might not be currently in the `staging` branch. What is the commands `git branch` and `eb list` outputs?

Comment: Actually I fixed it was somthing else failing deployment but my ENV vars also get revereted and I think my code was not reached to server. Thanks for help